# Bootstrap: A blank column which isn't in code, but it is in grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a list in bootstrap based on col's. This list is split to 3 columns at one line, like below:

```
<div class="col-md-4>Sth here, ofc max 12</div><div class="col-md-4>Sth here, ofc max 12</div><div class="col-md-4>Sth here, ofc max 12</div>
<div class="col-md-4>Sth here, ofc max 12</div><div class="col-md-4>Sth here, ofc max 12</div><div class="col-md-4>Sth here, ofc max 12</div>
<div class="col-md-4>Sth here, ofc max 12</div><div class="col-md-4>Sth here, ofc max 12</div><div class="col-md-4>Sth here, ofc max 12</div>
<div class="col-md-4>Sth here, ofc max 12</div>
```

I am trying to find out why the last column is centered.

I have tried `float: left` and position: options but without success.

*Interesting fact: When I change last col, for example, to `col-md-8` - it isn't centered, but is push to right side. When I change this to `col-md-9` it is on the next line. It looks like before it was invisible `col-md-4`

Comment: The Bootstrap markup is [fine](http://www.codeply.com/go/uKDZjgHisj). Post all of the relevant HTML and CSS. There could also be an issue if your content causes the columns to be different hieghts.

Comment: You do not want to apply your own style to individual **col-x-x**. It is hard to maintain in the future.

Comment: You could start by adding close quotation marks to see if it fixes the problem: class="col-md-4"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry all Stackoverflow-friends for imprecise question. In the Bootstrap markup I was "something special", with isn't listed in question ;)

```
.col-centered {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}
```

This class center bootstrap cols next to one - but `display: inline-block;` has issue. See for example [this](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/). So to prevent this they are several method. I'm added a blank comment between div's:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-centered">
        Sth
    </div><!--
    --><div class="col-xs-6 col-centered">
        Sth
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

See if a override is happening in the css, bootstrap cols should work fine